# TranslateY on scroll flickers with certain browsers

Tags: html, css, angular

To change the scroll sensitivity/speed I assigned `transfrom: translateY(x)` to the element with x being a dynamic number. That number changes according to the current scroll position:

```
@HostListener('document:scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll($event) {
  this.translateScrollable = (scrollY) / 1.5;
}
```

Chrome, Mozilla etc. work fine, but opening it f.e. on Edge will end up in a flickering-feast. How can I solve this?

Comment: What languages/framework are you using?

Comment: @symlink Angular, but that shouldn't matter in this case, since it should be a CSS problem - I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `will-change` property on the element that will be modified with the transform.

```css
.element-with-transform {
  will-change: transform;
}
```

> What this does is that it promotes the elements to another layer, so the browser doesn’t have to consider the layout render or painting.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)

You may also want to consider adding a throttle on the event, to limit the amount of times the call back is fired.